# Unsplitting a data frame by a variable (different length of factors)

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data-management

I have a data frame (st1) that I split by a factor. I then performed functions to the split data (i.e. mean) by another factor and hence, I cannot perform unsplit any more because my original data frame is of different length now.

As to walk you through what I did, here is a code:

```
NT = data.table(st1)

NT2=split (NT, NT$bin)

NT3 <- data.frame(sapply( NT2 , function(x) x[, list(ang=length(unique(thetadeg)), len=length(T), Vm=mean(V)), by=c("A")]))
```

head of the st1:

> structure(list(A = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), T = 56:61, 
>       X = c(481.07, 487.04, 490.03, 499, 504.97, 507.96), Y = c(256.97, 
>       256.97, 256.97, 256.97, 256.97, 256.97), V = c(4.482, 5.976, 
>       7.47, 4.482, 5.976, 7.47), thetarad = c(0.164031585831919, 
>       0.169139558949956, 0.171661200692621, 0.179083242584008, 
>       0.183907246800473, 0.186289411097781), thetadeg = c(9.39831757286096, 
>       9.69098287432395, 9.83546230358968, 10.2607139792383, 10.537109061132, 
>       10.6735970214433), bin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L), .Label = c("binA", "binB", "binC", "outbin"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A",  "T", "X", "Y", "V", "thetarad",
>   "thetadeg", "bin"), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")

I did not put a dput(head) for my NT3 because it will be too long.

I tried unsplit, unlist but am not successful. What I want to do is to have one data frame again with the bin as a factor.

Any help would be great.

edit: What I would like my data frame to have is A, ang, len, Vm, and bin as headers.

Comment: It might make more sense to, instead of using `split`, simply use the `by=bin` argument in data.table

Comment: Take a look at the [Intro to data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf). You probably need from page 6 onwards, fast grouping section.

Answer (score 1):

It's not altogether clear what your intended output is, but looking at what you have for `NT3`, this may be more effective:

```
NT <- data.table(ST1, key="A")
NT[, list(ang=length(unique(thetadeg))
              , len=length(T)
              , Vm=mean(V))
   , by=list(A, bin) ]
```

Comment: Ricardo, just curious, why are you using `.SD` here?  I haven't actually read the question (sorry), but from your answer I can't figure out how this is different to just putting the `list` piece directly inside `NT[, j=,]`.

Comment: Shouldn't you also have by/key "bin" somewhere?

Comment: If I use the `by=bin` in the `data table`, the second script just gives me values from binA and not from the other bins.

Comment: why not: `NT[, list(ang=length(unique(thetadeg)), len=length(T), Vm=mean(V)), by=A]` I've never seen the use of .SD like this, perhaps it would be interesting to describe more the answer

Comment: @MartínBel this is what I did (please see the code up that I wrapped in sapply). The problem is not with this function but with how will I unsplit my data frame according to a factor (bin).

Comment: @BrodieG & Martin, you are absolutely correct. Sloppy mistake on my part..   I had put that together cutting and pasting from the OP. Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what I did wrong, so this now works:

```
NT <- data.table(st1, key="bin")
NT2=NT[, list(ang=length(unique(thetadeg)), len=length(T), Vm=mean(V)), by=c("A", "bin")]
```

Apparently I could already do in `data.table` the by statement which was also suggested by @Ricardo Saporta. Thank you for that!